# single page scroll to change image effect (transition)

Tags: javascript, css, html

demo : http://kitkat.com/

is this html5? or it's achievable with js and css? I assume it's combination of tons of images, but it's impressive because the transition is so smooth!

Comment: That is called _parallax scrolling_. See [skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) for even more _smooth_ animations. For it you just need to know **HTML** adn **CSS**.

Comment: Note: [http://kitkat.com/](http://kitkat.com/) uses [skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr).

Answer (score 0):

Very first transitions you can do using a canvas , and after that is parallax which can be made by both of html/css versions